# jQuery $(this).find not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am making an accordion with a long list of articles.

I have the jQuery working when I use the following, only it will slideUp/Down every article on the page:

```
$('article a').click(function() {
    $('article').find('h3').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

In theory this should work, but it doesn't do a thing:

```
$('article a').click(function() {
    $(this).find('h3').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/CfqGG/

Where am I  going wrong?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In theory that should *not* work because in your click event, `this` refers to the `<a>`, not the `<article>`, because your click event is bound to `<a>`.

Try this:

```
$('article a').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().find('h3').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

Answer (score 7):

```
$(this).siblings('h3').slideToggle('fast');
```

`this` refers to the `a` element, and `find` searches an element in its `descendants`. `h3` is not a descendant but a sibling.

Answer (score 5):

You need this:

```
$('article a').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('article').find('h3').slideToggle('fast');
});
```

### [Check out the DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CfqGG/1/)

Answer (score 1):

In your code, `$('article a')` and subsequently `$(this)` is looking inside of the anchor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the updates code, check it out, you need specify the its sibling, cheers

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    //hides articles
    $('article h3').hide();  
    //article accordian
    $('article a').click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('h3').slideToggle('fast');
    });
});
```